# Structure not returned to client using thrift c_glib client

Tags: c, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am trying to implement client/ server program in c (c_glib) using thrift.

I have implemented the client/ server passing variables as function arguments. Now I need to pass structure as function argument.

The thrift file am using is given below

```
#!/usr/local/bin/thrift --gen c_glib


struct packet {
        1: i32 header,
        2: i32 data
}

service Calculator {
        void ping(),
        i32 calculate(1:i32 id, 2:i32 num),
        void stop_transfer(),
        void set_packet(1:packet pac_data)

}
```

The steps which I followed for passing the structure is :

- In client side
  1. g_object_new(TYPE_PACKET, NULL)
  2. Pass the pointer of structure to the server. calculator_if_set_packet (client, trans_packet, &error)
  3. g_object_get(tans_packet, "header", &head, "data", &dat, NULL) to get the data set in server
  4. Print the structure to show that the data set in server is reflected back in client

The client side relevant code is given below

```
int main (void) 
{
    gint head;
    gint dat;

    packet *trans_packet;

    trans_packet = g_object_new (TYPE_PACKET, NULL);

    if(!error && calculator_if_set_packet (client, trans_packet, &error)) {
        g_object_get((packet *) trans_packet,
             "header", &head,
             "data", &dat,
             NULL);

        printf("struct->header : %d\n", head);
        printf("struct->data : %d\n", dat);
    }

    g_object_unref (trans_packet);

}
```

- In server side
  1. g_object_get(pac_data, "header", &header, "data", &data, NULL) to get the properties of pac_data
  2. g_object_setg_object_get(tans_packet, "header", 111, "data", 999, NULL)

The server side function is given below

```
static gboolean 
tutorial_calculator_handler_set_packet(CalculatorIf *iface,
                                  const packet * pac_data,
                                  GError **error)
{
    gint header;
    gint data;

    THRIFT_UNSED_VAR (iface);
    THRIFT_UNUSED_VAR (error);

    g_object_get((packet *) pac_data,
             "header", &header,
             "data", &data,
             NULL);

    g_object_set((packet *) pac_data,
             "header", 123,
             "data", 999,
             NULL);

    return TRUE;
}
```

When am doing this, the server is not returning anything to the client when am calling calculator_if_set_packet().

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Is `struct packet` supposed to be using C syntax?  As written it does not.  ***[C bit field](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)***

Comment: Yes __struct packet__ is supposed to be in C syntax. The numbering is mandatory as this mentions the _required_ and _optional_ fields in the structure.

Comment: The numbers would result in _an invalid struct field declaration_ error.  They are not correct for C syntax.  Is this supposed to represent a bit field?

Comment: Without function prototypes I can only guess as how you need to pass structs, either by value, or by reference.  The code below provides examples of both.   ***[Review for C struct](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)***

Comment: "*Yes struct packet is supposed to be in C syntax*" - **Wrong**. Everything above including `struct packet` is [Thrift IDL](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl), not C or C++. "*When am doing this, the server is not returning anything to the client when am calling calculator_if_set_packet()*" - why don't you show that code?

Comment: @JensG I have added the relevant code parts. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: "*When am doing this, the server is not returning anything to the client when am calling calculator_if_set_packet().*" - Err, what return value would you expect to be returned to the client if the method is defined as `void set_packet(1:packet pac_data)`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned return type. But now I have updated the .thrift file and the codes. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the solution for the above problem.

I changed the thrift file as follows :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/thrift --gen c_glib

struct packet {
    1: i32 header,
    2: i32 data
}

service Calculator {
    void ping(),
    i32 calculate(1:i32 id, 2:i32 num),
    void stop_transfer(),
    packet set_packet(1:packet pac_data)
}
```

The corresponding modification in client and server part as given below :

**In client part**

```
int main (void) 
{
    gint head;
    gint dat;

    packet *trans_packet;
    packet *ret_packet;

    trans_packet = g_object_new (TYPE_PACKET, NULL);
    ret_packet = g_object_new (TYPE_PACKET, NULL);

    if(!error && calculator_if_set_packet (client, &ret_packet, trans_packet, &error)) {
        g_object_get((packet *) ret_packet,
             "header", &head,
             "data", &dat,
             NULL);

        printf("struct->header : %d\n", head);
        printf("struct->data : %d\n", dat);
    }

    g_object_unref (trans_packet);
    g_object_unref (ret_packet);
}
```

**In server part**

```
static gboolean 
tutorial_calculator_handler_set_packet(CalculatorIf *iface,
                              packet ** _return,
                              const packet * pac_data,
                              GError **error)
{
    gint header;
    gint data;

    THRIFT_UNSED_VAR (iface);
    THRIFT_UNUSED_VAR (error);

    g_object_get((packet *) pac_data,
             "header", &header,
             "data", &data,
             NULL);

    g_object_set(*_return,
             "header", 123,
             "data", 999,
             NULL);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Now whatever I set in the server am getting that in client.

If there is any other solution, do update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The struct you have shown is not using C syntax, even for a bit field:

```
struct packet {  //Not C syntax
        1: i32 header, //1nvalid struct field declaration
        2: i32 data    //invalid struct field declaration
}                      //missing ;
```

You are not showing the prototype of your function(s) that take a struct as an argument, but say for example your struct was defined as such:

```
typedef struct {
    int header;
    int data;
} PACKET;  //symbol PACKET would be used like your "struct packet"
```

Then using this typedef, you can create an instance, and a pointer to that struct like this:

PACKET packet, *pPacket;

In main, you can initialize the pointer by using the instance, like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    //pointer   instance
      pPacket = &packet;
      pPacket = malloc(sizeof(PACKET));//provide memory for pointer
      ...

      free(pPacket);//free dynamic memory 
      return 0;
}
```

Then, say for example you have one function prototype that takes an instance, and another that takes a pointer to that struct:

```
void someFunc1(PACKET pkt);  // takes an instance of PACKET
void someFunc2(PACKET *pkt);  //takes an instance of PACKET *
```

Then in main, you can pass then like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    pPacket = &packet;  //initialize pointer using instance
    pPacket = malloc(sizeof(PACKET));//provide memory for pointer

    someFunc1(packet);  //pass instance of PACKET
    someFunc2(pPacket); //pass pointer to PACKET
    someFunc2(&packet); //same as previous
    ...
    free(pPacket);//free dynamic memory 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ryker I believe you have not understood the question. Here I am using thrift. I have mentioned that in the question (1st line).By using thrift, the code will be auto generated, we only need to write the server and client application.

Comment: @DeerajSoman - Yes, I noted that, but  In the comments above you confirmed that the struct _should be_ using C construct (syntax).  It does not.  The example I provide above is addressing your title question regarding why structures are not passing.

Comment: I understand that sentence in the same way => @DeerajSoman, you should refine the question and include **all** relevant code parts.

Comment: @JensG I have included all relevant code parts. Kindly have a look and provide assistance.